# httppost периодически не видит HttpContext.Current.Request.Files

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http-post

Контроллер периодически не видит файл, который посылатся ему в post

```
[ResponseType(typeof(PersonSignature))]
    [Route("api/Acceptance/UploadSignatures/{scheduledWorkId:int}/{acceptanceGuid}/{operativeName}/{supervisorSignature:bool}/"), HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult UploadAcceptanceFiles(int scheduledWorkId, string acceptanceGuid, string operativeName, bool supervisorSignature)
    {
        var imageFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0 ? HttpContext.Current.Request.Files[0] : null;
```

На идентичный Post `imageFile` то `null` то нет. Post делаю из Postman. Пробовал другими способами. Результат тот-же.

Comment: Возможно asp-у не нравится enctype http://htmlbook.ru/html/form/enctype Какой из типов post вы используете?

Comment: Посылаю Content-Type: multipart/form-data; Если посылать в цикле То раза с 10 он его видит.

Comment: А с браузера - картинка загружается? Может Postman криво запрос делает...?

Comment: Да в том-то дело, что неважно чем. Результат тот-же. причем если грузить файлы .cs берет все. Если .png то через раз (файл один и тот-же).

Comment: Считать тело запроса можете? Png файл 16 на 16 или 8 на 8 пикселей есть баг? Если да - опубликуйте "тело" запроса. `Request.InputStream` хранит тело запроса. Возможно по какой-то причине клиент "теряет" картинку.

Comment: Прикрепленные файлы - на них "особые" правила. Возможно одно из этих правил вы нарушаете, поэтому не получаете файл. Например если у вас валидатор стоит, вы отправили файл - а у вас сработал "валидатор" на сервере - то при отправке запроса повторно (исправленого запроса) - файла уже не будет (что б он был, нужно в input поле опять выбрать файл).

Comment: Не хватает данных что бы оценить, у вас действительно баг ASP сервера или у вас проблема с "клиентом". Опубликуйте тело. Возможно видя "тело" вы сразу получите ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: http://my.jetscreenshot.com/demo/20180416-xiim-81kb.jpg  я так понимаю что проблема в этом: 'HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'?

Comment: Например так `Request.InputStream.Position =0; Request.InputStream.Read(b,0,b.Length);` и обьявить достаточно большой массив `b`. (4096 байт, или лучше размер png + 256 байт). Потом массив сохранить в текстовый файл. Тогда будет понятно что на входе. По "разделительным" меткам разбить файл на строки.

Comment: Вот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/661864/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-asp-web-api вопрос как получить тело, впринципе может... так и подойдёт. Получится не точная копия, но можно будет понять есть файл в запросе, или он просто не пришёл.

Comment: Из скрина - длинна - 5279 - наверное запрос содержит файл.

Comment: Ну... можно схитрить, набрать в Ctril+Alt+Q написать туда `System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(((System.Web.HttpInputStream)(Request.InputStream))._data._data)` и потом нажать на "увеличитель".

Comment: У меня запрос содержит `-----------------------------309
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file1"; filename="6.gif"
Content-Type: image/gif  GIF89a1` и картинка всегда приходит...